# How to train the machine to read xray image in correct position?

Tags: python, deep-learning, dataset, cnn, image-classification

I have trained a model to classify Xray of various body parts using CNN.
Now I want the model to read a Xray image in correct position even if input image is given in wrong position(rotated).

I think we can use letter R in chest xray to make machine to read them in correct position but I have no idea how.
I want to do this in python.
kindly help me.
Iam a newbie to DL.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be able to read rotated images, then simply add rotated images to the dataset and re-train it, you can even just add rotations of other images in the dataset. This is a common practice in image recognition, and you don't need to use the letter R unless you want to use classical computing to detect it and then rotate the image before feeding it into the network, but I'm not sure you would want to do that in your case given that albeit xrays are somewhat standardized, there's always the possibility that some kid slightly rotated their arm or something, so creating a model that is more robust to rotation is likely the best option.